How to send Shift+Enter when pressing Enter in a webpage?
I tried to intercept all enters in a page and send Shift+enter, it creates an endless loop of shift enters. After adding the logic to skip 'Shift+Enter', it sends the 'Enter' first, then a 'Shift+Enter'. I am confused with the result. How to handle this?
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        const myevent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
            key: 'Enter',
            shiftKey: true,
            bubbles: true
        });
        
        //  alert('Test Enter');
        event.target.dispatchEvent(myevent);
    }
});

Please note: I use 'User JavaScript and CSS' to load this js to work on any webpage, especially in chatgpt website.

Wouldn’t you also need to check for any modifiers?

Thanks, After adding that too, it send the enter first then shift enter second.


Register document to the "keyup" event.

If the key.code is "Enter" then cancel it with .preventDefault().

Reassign the event object as the new KeyboardEvent with .type "keydown". Add code: "Enter" and shiftKey: true to the options object.

Trigger new KeyboardEvent with .dispatchEvent().

Define a variable that confirms that "shiftKey" was triggered:
let shift = event.shiftKey ? "Shift" : null;


Log the event to confirm:
console.log(`Event: ${event.type}, Key: ${event.code} + ${shift}`);





document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

  if (event.code === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  
  event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    code: 'Enter',
    shiftKey: true,
    bubbles: true
  });

  this.dispatchEvent(event);
  
  let shift = event.shiftKey ? "Shift" : null;
  
  console.log(`Event: ${event.type}, Key: ${event.code} + ${shift}`);

});
<p>Click here then hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.</p>




I would suggest using early returns like this


document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key !== 'Enter') {
    return
  }
  if (event.shiftKey === true) {
    return
  }
  event.preventDefault();

  const myevent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: 'Enter',
    shiftKey: true,

    bubbles: true
  });

  console.debug('shift+enter')

  event.target.dispatchEvent(myevent);
});




Why would this do anything different than the OPs code?

@Bergi my code did not produce an endless loop when I ran it. Apparently OP has edited their code, so it shouldn't produce and endless loop either. I guess they've answered their own question. Weird, huh…
